# function click() is not working [Rails 3.2 + jquery]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

in my index.html.erb I have:

```
<button type="button" id="clean">Clean</button>
```

**This button is add after by action "something.js.erb".**
So, in application.js:

```
$(function () {
    $('button#clean').click(function(){
        $('#target').remove(); 
    });
});
```

why is not working? When I put this script into html, it's work.

Answer (score 2):

Use "on function" in a correct format.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button#clean', function () {
    $('#target').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing your .js file in your HTML ??

Also Hit F12 to check for any errors in the console section

If you see no errors then try to attach the event handler using **.on()**

```
$('button#clean').on('click', function() {
});
```

Comment: Yes,such: <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"/>

Comment: Try placing a alert in DOm ready event and check if jQuery was loaded properly in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your loading jQuery beforehand and I suggest using the following code

```
 $('button#clean').on("click", function() {
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your console to ensure there are no errors and ensure you've included application.js and jQuery within your HTML.

index.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/application.js"></script>
```

application.js

```
(function ($) {
  $('button#clean').click(function () {
    $('#target').remove();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Don't appears nothing in console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want page specific js to be executed before going to the index.html for foo_controller then do

```
assets/javascripts/foo/index.js
```

and place

```
$(function () {
    $('button#clean').click(function(){
        $('#target').remove(); 
    });
});
```